# Iterate Data frame and use those value in Spark SQL statement

Tags: scala, apache-spark-sql

I have a data frame say

DF

```
Animal
======
Cat
Dog
Horse
```

I want to iterate these values and use them in Spark SQL statement.

Can someone please help me with this?

Comment: Can you please explain what kind of iteration you want to do ? How you plan to use them in SQL ?

Comment: I want to use this values of dataframe and further use in another table one by one.. (hope this answers your question above)

Comment: I tried something like this : DF.foreach {row=> row.toSeq.foreach{col=> spark.sql(s"select '{row}' ")}}

Comment: Dataframes are not supposed to be used like this. you can use an array instead of Dataframe

Comment: Could you please explain a bit more? My objective is that I have to iterate value of DF and use them in Spark SQL...

Answer (score 0):

Spark dataset/dataframe APIs are more declarative than imperative (like SQL) that means you describe what you want the end data to be and let the spark engine figure out the exact transformation.

What you're describing doesn't make sense as a use case for spark

Comment: Yeah I know I am doing wrong here.. as I said before I have to iterate through a dataframe and use those values in Spark SQL ...

Comment: no - you can think of the dataframe as a table (in fact you can register it as one with df.registerTempTable("name") ) and then use that with other tables/dataframes in the SQL (i.e. you'd probably join it /cross join it etc.)

Answer (score 0):

It's a weird use case, but you can iterate over your values an do whatever you want with a foreach.

**INPUT**

```
df.show
+------+
|animal|
+------+
|   cat|
|   dog|
| horse|
+------+
```

**SENTENCE**

Same as I used a print, you can do any other function, but as in the comments said, it's a bit weird

```
df.foreach(row => println(row.getAs[String](0)))
```

With this piece you get the actual value

```
row.getAs[String](0)
```